# Materialize CSS Dropdown update DOM innerText

Tags: javascript, materialize

I have a dropdown menu made with Materialize CSS. I'm trying to change the text on a "button" when the user clicks it, but for some reason it just won't update the DOM.

```js
var changeText;
changeText = function(){
  if(this.innerText === 'test'){
    this.innerText = 'success';
  } else {
    this.innerText = 'test';
  }
  
  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
    alignment: 'right',
    constrainWidth: false,
    coverTrigger: false
  });
  
  console.log(this.innerText);
};

$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
    alignment: 'right',
    constrainWidth: false,
    coverTrigger: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeText()">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried re-initializing the dropdown trigger hoping that would update the DOM, but it has no effect. The innerText is changed as expected though as you can see in the console log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers window object here. So try `event.target`

```js
var changeText;
changeText = function(){
  if(event.target.innerText === 'test'){
    event.target.innerText = 'success';
  } else {
    event.target.innerText = 'test';
  }  
  console.log(this.innerText);
};

$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
    alignment: 'right',
    constrainWidth: false,
    coverTrigger: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeText()">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Amazing! This seems to be perfect :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To refer element you have to pass reference like below

```
var changeText;
changeText = function(ele){
  if(ele.innerText === 'test'){
    ele.innerText = 'success';
  } else {
    ele.innerText = 'test';
  }

  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
    alignment: 'right',
    constrainWidth: false,
    coverTrigger: false
  });

};

$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
    alignment: 'right',
    constrainWidth: false,
    coverTrigger: false
  });
});





<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeText(this)">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks :) It's not the most elegant solution, but it works ^^

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the `window`, update the `innerText` of `$('.dropdown-trigger')[0]` :

```js
var changeText;
changeText = function(e) {
  if (e.innerText === 'test') {
    $('.dropdown-trigger')[0].innerText = 'success';
  } else {
    $('.dropdown-trigger')[0].innerText = 'test';
  }

  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
    alignment: 'right',
    constrainWidth: false,
    coverTrigger: false
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({
    alignment: 'right',
    constrainWidth: false,
    coverTrigger: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeText(this)">test</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeText(this)">test 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will accept the other answer though because I cant directly target a single menu (there are multiple ones). So using the event seems to make more sense :)